# maven scm plugin deleting output folder in every execution

Tags: svn, version-control, maven-2, svn-checkout, maven-scm

I need to download from 2 different svn locations to the same output directory. So i configured  2 different executions. But every time it executes a checkout deletes the output directory so it also deletes the already      downloaded projects.

Here is a sample of my pom.xml:

```
<profile>
  <id>checkout</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>checkout</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <username>${svn.username}</username>
          <password>${svn.pass}</password>
          <checkoutDirectory>${path}</checkoutDirectory>
          <skipCheckoutIfExists/>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>checkout_a</id>
            <configuration>
              <connectionUrl>scm:svn:https://host_n/folder</connectionUrl>
              <checkoutDirectory>${path}</checkoutDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>checkout</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>checkout_b</id>
            <configuration>
              <connectionUrl>scm:svn:https://host_l/anotherfolder</connectionUrl>
              <checkoutDirectory>${path}</checkoutDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>checkout</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Is there any way to prevent the executions to  delete the folder ${path}  ?

---

I came up with a solution but I cant get it to work:

I added  to the profile a execution of maven-clean-plugin:

```
<profile>
  <id>checkout</id>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>not-clean</id>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${path}</directory>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>*/*</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But I cant realize how to exclude everything in folder.

Any Idea?

Comment: To format code, indent every line by four spaces.

Comment: May you can explain why you need to checkout code inside Maven ? And why do you need two locations? Shouldn't that be done by a Continious Integration Server (e.g. Hudson?)

Comment: Ah...you can't checkout twice into the same target location with Subversion and no other VCT.

Comment: @Aaron: I've made it but it doesn seems to work for me. Well I placed a ` char at the beginning of the pom.xml and another one at the end. Maybe is that the problem.

@khmarbaise: It is  not a new project. It is made that way, I know it  isnt the best way. I need to know if that is possible. 

Thank you  both for your  comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: Put each SVN location in a Maven module (a sub-project) and then create a third project which contains the code to join the two.

Background: With Maven, you always have one project per POM.xml. If you feel that you need to join data from several places, create modules and then use a parent POM to join them into one "reactor project".

To build, invoke Maven in the parent "reactor project".

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. But I cant actually modify the structure of the projects (its a multi module project).

Comment: Then you're already halfway there. I am talking about a multi module project. The fact is that you can't checkout two SCM sources into the same folder since each call will remove everything that can't be found in the source. So you must checkout to two different places *or* you must use a custom ant task. See the antrun plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the source of the maven-scm-plugin. Added functionality I needed.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: where is modified source?